# Edge detection in low contrast images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have some images which have some objects of my interest. The objects have very low contrast w.r.t. background and I would like to detect the edges of these objects in these low-contrast images. Any suggestions?

An example image is shown below (objects are the rectangles in the right side of the image and the edges are their boundaries).

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you initially apply basic gray scale modificiations such as **gamma** , **contrast** etc.

Here is the result of performing such a simple processing:

[image]
[image]

It's now a more recognizable image at least for a human viewer and I believe the software algorithm will also perform better, provided it was not already doing it...